# There is something wrong When I use the Google tutorial "Fine-tuning a model from an existing checkpoint"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using the python-tensorflow to build a model to train my data. I refer to the google tutorial about the pre-trained inception_v4 model.Here is the link:[Fine-tuning a model from an existing checkpoint](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim).
When I run the code

```
$ python train_image_classifier.py --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
--dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} --dataset_name=flowers \
--dataset_split_name=train --model_name=inception_v4 \
--checkpoint_path=${CHECKPOINT_PATH} \
--checkpoint_exclude_scopes=InceptionV4/Logits,InceptionV4/AuxLogits \
--trainable_scopes=InceptionV4/Logits,InceptionV4/AuxLogits
```

there are some mistakes.

[Error infomation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q4P4.png)

I am wondering what can I do to fix it? Or is there any other way to use the google pre-trained inception_v4 model?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That image is **huge**. Copy the text of the error messages and paste it in here, instead of posting a gigantic image. Error messages are **text**, not images. .Images should be used only when there is no other way to demonstrate the problem, not as a way to save effort. Remember that people here use this site on mobile devices and some have to deal with corporate proxies that won't allow images. Your post is unreadable to those users, and unkind to people using metered connecttions.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. Probably you don't have TF-GPU; it looks like it's trying to assign an op to GPU and instead defaulting to CPU.

Comment: Hi ,Ken White,thanks for your advice! I am new here and don't know about it, I'll take your advice in the future. Actually I tried to post text at first, however I've gotten a warning saying my code was not formatted properly.

Comment: Hi, Evan! thanks for your advice. I've solved my problem with another way.